# How to zip iterators in parallel using threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, iterator, generator

Say I have **N** generators that produce a stream of items `gs = [..] # list of generators`.

I can easily `zip` them together to get a generator of tuples from each respective generator in `gs`: `tuple_gen = zip(*gs)`.

This calls `next(g)` on each `g` in sequence in `gs` and gathers the results in a tuple. But if each item is costly to produce we may want to parallelize the work of `next(g)` on multiple threads.

How can I implement a `pzip(..)` that does this?

Comment: a) Which OS? b) How big is N? c) Is the time to produce an item for each generator fairly equal?  d) Are you aware of the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)? If your generators involve cpu-bound work within Python (not I/0 or utilization of GIL-releasing C-extensions like numpy ), you're going to need processes for truely parallel execution.

Comment: 1. Ubuntu. 2. N~32 3. Yes. 4. IO bound reading from files.

Comment: If you are bound by disk access then more threads are not likely to help you, since the limit is raw disk access speed in most cases. However, if you are IO bound and waiting (i.e. for user input or for slow network connections) it may be very beneficial to run multiple threads.

Comment: related: Truly parallel generator using _processes_ covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64288667/9059420).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you asked for can be achieved by creating a generator which yields the results from `apply_async`-calls on a ThreadPool.

FYI, I benchmarked this approach with `pandas.read_csv`-iterators you get with specifying the `chunksize` parameter. I created eight copies of a 1M rows sized csv-file and specified chunksize=100_000.

Four of the files were read with the sequential method you provided, four with the `mt_gen` function below, using a pool of four threads:

> - single threaded ~ 3.68 s
> - multi-threaded ~ 1.21 s

Doesn't mean it will improve results for every hardware and data-setup, though.

```
import time
import threading
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool  # dummy uses threads


def _load_sim(x = 10e6):
    for _ in range(int(x)):
        x -= 1
    time.sleep(1)


def gen(start, stop):
    for i in range(start, stop):
        _load_sim()
        print(f'{threading.current_thread().name} yielding {i}')
        yield i


def multi_threaded(gens):
    combi_g = mt_gen(gens)
    for item in combi_g:
        print(item)


def mt_gen(gens):
    with Pool(N_WORKERS) as pool:
        while True:
            async_results = [pool.apply_async(next, args=(g,)) for g in gens]
            try:
                results = [r.get() for r in async_results]
            except StopIteration:  # needed for Python 3.7+, PEP 479, bpo-32670
                return
            yield results


if __name__ == '__main__':

    N_GENS = 10
    N_WORKERS = 4
    GEN_LENGTH = 3

    gens = [gen(x * GEN_LENGTH, (x + 1) * GEN_LENGTH) for x in range(N_GENS)]
    multi_threaded(gens)
```

Output:

```
Thread-1 yielding 0
Thread-2 yielding 3
Thread-4 yielding 6
Thread-3 yielding 9
Thread-1 yielding 12
Thread-2 yielding 15
Thread-4 yielding 18
Thread-3 yielding 21
Thread-1 yielding 24
Thread-2 yielding 27
[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27]
Thread-3 yielding 7
Thread-1 yielding 10
Thread-2 yielding 4
Thread-4 yielding 1
Thread-3 yielding 13
Thread-1 yielding 16
Thread-4 yielding 22
Thread-2 yielding 19
Thread-3 yielding 25
Thread-1 yielding 28
[1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28]
Thread-1 yielding 8
Thread-4 yielding 2
Thread-3 yielding 11
Thread-2 yielding 5
Thread-1 yielding 14
Thread-4 yielding 17
Thread-3 yielding 20
Thread-2 yielding 23
Thread-1 yielding 26
Thread-4 yielding 29
[2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26, 29]

Process finished with exit code 0
```