# Given N generators, is it possible to create a generator that runs them in parallel processes and yields the zip of those generators?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, generator, python-multiprocessing

Suppose I have N generators `gen_1, ..., gen_N` where each on them will yield the same number of values. I would like a generator `gen` such that it runs gen_1, ..., gen_N in N parallel processes and yields `(next(gen_1), next(gen_2), ... next(gen_N))`

That is I would like to have:

```
def gen():
   yield (next(gen_1), next(gen_2), ... next(gen_N))
```

in such a way that each gen_i is running on its own process. Is it possible to do this? I have tried doing this in the following dummy example with no success:

```
A = range(4)

def gen(a):
    B = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    for b in B:
        yield b + str(a)

def target(g):
    return next(g)

processes = [Process(target=target, args=(gen(a),)) for a in A]

for p in processes:
    p.start()

for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

However I get the error `TypeError: cannot pickle 'generator' object`.

EDIT:

I have modified @darkonaut answer's a bit to fit my needs. I am posting it in case some of you find it useful. We first define a couple of utility functions:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
from typing import List, Generator


def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=iter([])):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)

def split_generators_into_batches(generators: List[Generator], n_splits):
    chunks = grouper(generators, len(generators) // n_splits + 1)

    return [zip_longest(*chunk) for chunk in chunks]
```

The following class is responsible for splitting any number of generators into n (number of processes) batches and proccessing them yielding the desired result:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class GeneratorParallelProcessor:
SENTINEL = 'S'

def __init__(self, generators, n_processes = 2 * mp.cpu_count()):
    self.n_processes = n_processes
    self.generators = split_generators_into_batches(list(generators), n_processes)
    self.queue = mp.SimpleQueue()
    self.barrier = mp.Barrier(n_processes + 1)
    self.sentinels = [self.SENTINEL] * n_processes

    self.processes = [
        mp.Process(target=self._worker, args=(self.barrier, self.queue, gen)) for gen in self.generators
    ]

def process(self):
    for p in self.processes:
        p.start()

    while True:
        results = list(itertools.chain(*(self.queue.get() for _ in self.generators)))
        if results != self.sentinels:
            yield results
            self.barrier.wait()
        else:
            break

    for p in self.processes:
        p.join()

def _worker(self, barrier, queue, generator):
    for x in generator:
        queue.put(x)
        barrier.wait()
    queue.put(self.SENTINEL)
```

To use it just do the following:

```
parallel_processor = GeneratorParallelProcessor(generators)

    for grouped_generator in parallel_processor.process():
        output_handler(grouped_generator)
```

Comment: If you already have the generator objects, there's no general way to transplant them into another process.  You would need to start each `Process` with a target function that will create the generator there.

Comment: Even if you manage to do this, the GIL will probably prevent them from running in parallel.

Comment: @MarkRansom He's using `multiprocessing` and not threads, so I don't think the GIL applies here.

Comment: @thegamecracks sorry, I missed that; you're correct that it will remove the GIL from the equation.  But it does make data interchange more tricky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to get such an "**Unified Parallel Generator (UPG)**" (attempt to coin a name) with some effort, but as @jasonharper already mentioned, you definitely need to assemble the sub-generators within the child-processes, since a running generator can't be pickled.

The pattern below is re-usable with only the generator function `gen()` being custom to this example. The design uses [`multiprocessing.SimpleQueue`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.SimpleQueue) for returning generator results to the parent and  [`multiprocessing.Barrier`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Barrier) for synchronization.

Calling `Barrier.wait()` will block the caller (thread in any process) until the number of specified `parties` has called `.wait()`, whereupon all threads currently waiting on the `Barrier` get released simultaneously. The usage of `Barrier` here ensures further generator-results are only started to be computed *after* the parent has received *all* results from an iteration, which might be desirable to keep overall memory consumption in check.

The number of parallel workers used equals the number of argument-tuples you provide within the `gen_args_tuples`-iterable, so `gen_args_tuples=zip(range(4))` will use four workers for example. See comments in code for further details.

```
import multiprocessing as mp

SENTINEL = 'SENTINEL'


def gen(a):
    """Your individual generator function."""
    lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    for ch in lst:
        for _ in range(int(10e6)):  # some dummy computation
            pass
        yield ch + str(a)


def _worker(i, barrier, queue, gen_func, gen_args):
    for x in gen_func(*gen_args):
        print(f"WORKER-{i} sending item.")
        queue.put((i, x))
        barrier.wait()
    queue.put(SENTINEL)


def parallel_gen(gen_func, gen_args_tuples):
    """Construct and yield from parallel generators
     build from `gen_func(gen_args)`.
     """
    gen_args_tuples = list(gen_args_tuples)  # ensure list
    n_gens = len(gen_args_tuples)
    sentinels = [SENTINEL] * n_gens
    queue = mp.SimpleQueue()
    barrier = mp.Barrier(n_gens + 1)  # `parties`: + 1 for parent

    processes = [
        mp.Process(target=_worker, args=(i, barrier, queue, gen_func, args))
        for i, args in enumerate(gen_args_tuples)
    ]

    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    while True:
        results = [queue.get() for _ in range(n_gens)]
        if results != sentinels:
            results.sort()
            yield tuple(r[1] for r in results)  # sort and drop ids
            barrier.wait()  # all workers are waiting
            # already, so this will unblock immediately
        else:
            break

    for p in processes:
        p.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    for res in parallel_gen(gen_func=gen, gen_args_tuples=zip(range(4))):
        print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
WORKER-1 sending item.
WORKER-0 sending item.
WORKER-3 sending item.
WORKER-2 sending item.
('a0', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3')
WORKER-1 sending item.
WORKER-2 sending item.
WORKER-3 sending item.
WORKER-0 sending item.
('b0', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3')
WORKER-2 sending item.
WORKER-3 sending item.
WORKER-1 sending item.
WORKER-0 sending item.
('c0', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3')

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: thank you very much. This does the trick! I think this is very useful for compute intensive processes where you don't wan't to start over on every iteration. A library that helps python using multiprocessing in a simpler way would be extremely useful.

Comment: @creyesk You're welcome. Yeah, IIRC you're not the first one to ask for something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I went for a little different approach, you can modify the example below accordingly.
So somewhere in the main script initialize the pool according to your needs, you need just this 2 lines

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool(processes=4)
```

then you can define a generator function like this:
(Note that the generators input is assumed to be any iterable containing all the generators)

```
def parallel_generators(generators, pool):
results = ['placeholder']
while len(results) != 0:
    batch = pool.map_async(next, generators)  # defines the next round of values
    results = list(batch.get)  # actual calculation done here
    yield results
return
```

We define the results condition in the while loop like this because map objects with next and generators return an empty list when the generators stop producing values. So at that point we just terminate the parallel generator.

EDIT

So apparently multiproccecing pool, and map don't play good with generators making the above code not work as intended so **do not use** until later update.

As for the pickle error it seems some bound functions do not support pickle which is needed in the multiprocessing library in order to transfer objects and functions, for a workaround the pathos mutliprocessing library uses dill which solves the need for pickle and is an option you might want to try, searching in Stack Overflow for your error you can also find some more complicated solutions with custom code for pickling the functions needed.

Comment: It is a nice approach. However if I try to yield batch.get() then it actually runs the map async and I get the same `TypeError: cannot pickle 'generator' object.` Am I missing something?