# How to parallize/multithreading multiple generator initialization?

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, generator

I have multiple generators which need some time for initialization before each of the generators can yield the first result. In my code example below is an example. Each genearator needs 5 seconds for initialization. So the total time is 10s.
Is there a way to initialize `g1` and `g2` parallel? So that the total initialization time is only 5s?

```
from random import random
from time import sleep


def my_generator():
    sleep(5)
    for i in range(5):
        yield random()

# this is what I want to do in parallel
g1 = my_generator()
g2 = my_generator()

x = [(r1, r2) for r1, r2 in zip(g1, g2)]
```

Comment: What's really happening during that five seconds?  Are you waiting for an external event or a URL?  Is your code dealing with a complex calculation?  Are the generators completely stand-alone, or do the values they generate depend on other ongoing state?  All this can affect the answer.

Comment: @FrankYellin The generators are independent. The main part for the long initialization time are database requests because of big data. The calculations are minor complex

Comment: Sounds like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52376841/9059420) might work for you then.

Comment: @Darkonaut thank you very much but actually thats not exact what I need. The Problem is that I have to preserve the generator's yield orde.r I have to process the response of `g1` and `g2` at the same time. I think if the example above can be executed in parallel my problem is solved

Comment: I'm not sure if I really understand what you mean, but you can try with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64296722/9059420) for truly parallel. Just comment out `results.sort()` and calling with your example should be `list(parallel_gen(gen_func=my_generator, gen_args_tuples=[()] * 2)])`. But you'll pay a price in overhead for IPC during the yielding.

Answer (score 1):

I found a soulution with async:

```
import asyncio
from random import random
from aiostream import stream

async def my_generator():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    for i in range(5):
        yield random()

async def main():
    combine = stream.zip(my_generator(), my_generator())
    x = []
    async with combine.stream() as streamer:
        async for item in streamer:
            x.append(item)
    print(x)

asyncio.run(main())
```